# HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated never true

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

**Login**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel loginModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (var _Db = new AccountContext())
        {
            var _UserAccount = _Db.UserAccounts.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == loginModel.Username && u.Password == loginModel.Password);

            if (_UserAccount == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Account doesn't exist!");
            }
            else
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(loginModel.Username, false);
            }
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

**Redirect or display view**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return View("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("LoginPage");
    }
}
```

I've stepped through the code and can see the SetAuthCookie being called with the correct username.
`FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(loginModel.Username, false);`

**What could prevent the user from being authenticated?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What could prevent the user from being authenticated?

One possible reason is if you forgot to enable forms authentication in your web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    ...
</system.web>
```

You might also want to inspect whether a forms authentication cookie is being emitted in your browser after calling the SetAuthCookie method. By default this cookie will be called `.ASPXAUTH`. If such cookie is present and the ticket hasn't expired, the `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` method will return true.

Comment: The cookie was being sent, I've added the entry into the web config and it's now working. Thanks!

Comment: Hi! I know this is an old post, but I get this same problem and the .ASPXAUTH cookie is not emitted. Instead I have one named ASP.NET_SessionId. What could be the problem? Could it be that I run it under Mono-MonoDevelop?

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem, which continued even after adding the `<authentication mode="Forms">` tag to my web.config file. As I was in there, I noticed:

`<system.webServer>`
    `<modules>`
      `<remove name="FormsAuthentication" />`
    `</modules>`
`</system.webServer>`

I referred to another MVC project web.config file and saw a **difference**:

`<system.webServer>`
    `<modules>`
      `<remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />`
    `</modules>`
`</system.webServer>`

I changed the value to read `<remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />`, and voila! - It works now. Sorry I don't understand why, or what is happening there, but I am hopeful that may help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to authenticate the user first:

```
WebSecurity.Login(loginModel.UserName, loginModel.Password);
```

Only after that can you set the auth cookie.

Comment: I've not got access to WebSecurity is there a reference that I need to add?

Comment: Actually, are you using SimpleMembership? It looks like you're using a self made system, is that correct?

Comment: I'm not using SimpleMembership, but I was contemplating it.

Comment: In the end you need to integrate with the .NET infrastructure to be able to use the SetAuthCookie-method and call the IsAuthenticated-method. Otherwise there's no way .NET knows what a login means. A good start is to just create a new MVC internet application and look at how it's implemented. It's not that complicated actually (hence SimpleMembership ;-) ).